# Is memset(&ptr, 0, sizeof(ptr)); the same as ptr=NULL;?

Tags: c, pointers, null, language-lawyer, posix

May I set a pointer to `NULL` portably (at least according to the POSIX standard) by memsetting it to zero?  Or even memsetting the struct that contains it (where it becomes actually useful)?

Edit: POSIX specifies in `stddef.h(0posix)` that `NULL` shall be `(void *) 0`, but that may not be enough to allow `memset()`.  I ignore if there are any other details that POSIX defines regarding this.

Comment: No.  There's probably a duplicate question on this.

Comment: It'll work on any machine you're likely to use, but there are ([or have been](http://c-faq.com/null/machexamp.html)) machines where the bit pattern of a null pointer was *not* all-bits-0.

Comment: I know the C standard allowed those unicorn architectures.  But I thought POSIX might not, and couldn't find any answer that answers that for POSIX specifically.  I'd say that this is not 100% duplicate (although an answer about POSIX on any of the almost-duplicates would be ok for me, and actually better since it would keep everything together).

Comment: Apologies if I jumped the gun.  I overlooked where you mentioned Posix in your question.  I don't *think* Posix makes a different guarantee than the C standards do, but it might.

Comment: No problem. We all do at some point! :-)

Comment: I used to always `memset` newly-allocated structs to 0, then go back and manually set all pointer fields to `NULL`, just in case.  But my resolve is beginning to weaken after all these years.  If we were in a code review, and your code used plain memset to initialize some pointer-containing structs, I'd mention the issue for conversation's sake, but I probably wouldn't flag the code as unacceptable.

Comment: That's the reason I'm asking this. I never set to NULL after memset, but I saw some code that did, and at first I thought that was unnecessary (and 99.9% of the time it is), but then started wondering if I had been wrong on some assumption...

Comment: IIUC POSIX added this guarantee only to Issue 8 (next revision) draft https://www.austingroupbugs.net/view.php?id=940#c2696

Comment: Ahh, so that's the next POSIX revision!  Then I was wrong on this one :-)

Comment: @alx: No, you were correct. However, the cast is allowed (by the C standard, anyway) to create a new representation. For example, `(float)1` does not produce the same bit pattern as `1`. Saying that the all-zero bit pattern represents a null pointer is a different claim than saying that `(void*)0` is a null pointer.

Comment: That said, the POSIX change is based on the theory that there is no actual POSIX implementation on a platform in which the all-zero bit pattern is not a null pointer. So it was always safe in practice, but not previously guaranteed to be future-proof.

Comment: Reopened because whether this is true under POSIX is a different question than whether it is true only under the C or C++ standards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In **C**, `memset(&ptr, 0, sizeof(ptr))` is not necessarily the same as `ptr=NULL` since the ISO/IEC 9899:1999 clause 17.7 paragraph 3 says that `NULL`

> expands to an implementation-defined null pointer constant

Thus not necessarily an all-zero bit pattern.

**Posix** has not had a different guarantee than the **C** standard. However, the [next revision draft](https://www.austingroupbugs.net/view.php?id=940#c2696) says that

> POSIX additionally guarantees that any pointer object whose representation has all bits set to zero, perhaps by memset() to 0 or by calloc(), will be interpreted as a null pointer.

Hence it seems that **Posix** will guarantee that `memset(&ptr, 0, sizeof(ptr))` will have the same effect as `ptr=NULL` (and this is mostly likely already the case on all existing implementations). However, the statements will not necessarily assign identical bit patterns to `ptr`.

It is important to notice that the **C** standard (and **Posix**, also with the mentioned update) *does not* guarantee that the bit pattern of a null pointer is unique. Thus, in principle `ptr=NULL` could assign a different bit pattern to `ptr` than `memset(&ptr, 0, sizeof(ptr))` as long as this bit pattern is also a null pointer.

The standard *does* guarantee (clause 6.3.2.3 paragraph 4) that

> Any two null pointers shall compare equal.

Thus if `ptr` and `ptr2` are both null pointers, then `ptr == ptr2` evaluates to `true`. However, `memcmp(&ptr, &ptr2, sizeof(ptr))` may not evaluate to `0`.